# GCM notification not received on one of the mobile devices

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send GCM notification to the device xiaomi redmi 1s, not getting the notification on the device while the same notification is getting delivered to the other devices and the failure for message count is 0.Can anyone please tell the issue.I have debugged it not received any call on `onMessage` method.

> not got any message in the app either in the foreground or in the background state of the application,
>   the registration id is correct checked it in IDE.GCM response is 
>   **"success":2,"failure":0**

Comment: Check the **DEVICE ID** and  **TOKEN** are sending properly

Comment: checked both are right, the registration id is right debugged it.

Comment: Interact with the back end and check whether your **Device Id** is registered or not

Comment: @karthickraja : can u please elaborate or give a link

Answer (score 5):

Xiaomi for security purposes disables the Notification for each Application. Follow these steps to receive messages in background once they quit the app using cleaner.

- Enable Autostart
- Enable Floating and Lock Screen Notification

**Enable AutoStart**

- Open *Security* App.
- Got to *Permissions*, then Click on *Auto Start Management*.
- Add/Enable auto start apps (e.g. Whatsapp).

**Enable Floating and Lock Screen Notification**

- Open *Settings* App.
- Click on *Notifications*, then click on *Manage Notifications*.
- Tap on the App which you are looking for (e.g. WhatsApp).
- Enable *Show in notification shade / Show on lockscreen and in drop down* option.

For Reference check this out : http://support.hike.in/entries/55998480-I-m-not-getting-notification-on-my-Xiaomi-Phone-For-MIUI-6-

Comment: Not getting notification on the device still.

Comment: try opening app and then sending push notification to it.

Comment: its not receiving the notification in any state

Comment: please edit your question then and adding some relevant code.

Comment: may be your device has not been registered with `Registration_ID` needed for GCM. Do check it.