# GCM notification not received on some Devices

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

Trying to send GCM notification to the devices **asus,xiaomi redmi 1s** but not getting the notification while the same notification is getting delivered to the other devices.As given in link

[GCM notification not received on one of the mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33935521/gcm-notification-not-received-on-one-of-the-mobile-devices) 
these devices having security app such as **AutoStart** to disable app run in background on install.

So the question is **how to notify user to enable app in autostart?** Is there any programmatic way to deal with it because in our case if no GCM then there is no use of our app.

If you want any code then I can give it but as I stated above its(GCM) working on other devices and also work on above devices if app is enabled in Autostart,so I think there is no need to add code.
Thanks.

Comment: Try to send notification when app is running not in background see if it work or not

Comment: Its work if app in background.

Comment: on these devices asus,xiaomi redmi ? as well ?

Comment: Yes on both asus,xiaomi redmi 1s

Comment: if it is sending on these devices Then what is the issue ?

Comment: Background means if app in recent task list,not service.

Comment: yeah so what is your requirment

Comment: Did you read whole question ? anyway "how to notify user to enable app in autostart?" Or Is there any solution to work GCM even if app disabled by Autostart.

Comment: If your notification is deliver to user then why do you want to enable app

Comment: Who tell that notification deliver?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107007/discussion-between-khizar-hayat-and-giru-bhai).

Answer (score 1):

I have been dealing with the same issue from a long time. These devices specially redmi devices create a lot of problem . Redmi doesn't provide enough freedom to deal with notifications programatically. With every new install, you'll have to manually turn on autostart from 'Security' otherwise  push notifications might have erratic behaviour. Further you'll have to add

> GET_TASKS permission

in these devices which is deprecated

Comment: As shared link in my question I know that there is autostart app and that link give those Info but how can I tell users of my app to enable app in autostart,because I cannot target specific to xiaomi,I want generic method as asked in question.

Comment: After a lot of research i din't find any programatical way to check whether its Xiomi device or not .

Comment: Here is same,thats why asked question ;) Any way Is there any solution to work GCM even if app disabled by Autostart.

Comment: Nope , as far as i know .Thats y i hate xiomi :-p

Comment: But we cannot force user to use particular device to use our app.

Comment: your condition is better then mine,in my case the client purchased 50 devices for usage and all of then Redmi.